# jQuery - move element with javascript inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery to move a element that contains javascript code inside it, like this:

```
<li class="a1">
 <div class="el"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> document.write('Hello World'); </script>
    ...
 </div>
</li>

<li class="a2">     
</li>

<a class="trigger">link</a>
```

so I attached a click event on a.trigger that will move div.el into the 2nd list.
the problem is that the js inside it makes the browser to open a new window only with div.el inside it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use document.write** because it will cause headaches. Enhance progressively:

```
$(".el").html('Hello World');
```

And it will work just fine.